# Avoiding auto in template parameter lists

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a class template like this

```
template <auto Arg> class X;
```

But because I am using MSVC 2017.5, `auto` in template parameter lists is not supported and I have to write

```
template <typename T, T Arg> class X;
```

and name the type explicitely via `X<int, 5>` instead of using auto deduction. Now, is there a way to get to the same result without `auto` in template parameter lists?

---

Specifically I have the following problem.

```
template <typename C, typename T>
using Func = const T& (C::*)(void) const;

template <typename C, typename T, Func<C, T> F>
class X;
```

And I can use `X` like this:

```
class Y { const int &getInt() const; }

X<Y, int, &Y::getInt> x;
```

Of course I want to avoid the explicit naming of `Y` and `int` if possible.

Comment: Is using auto an option in the solution to your real problem, or do you actually want to avoid auto? It's not clear to me, if you have used it as an example only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only one recourse pre-C++17, and it isn't pretty or recommended. You must turn to the preprocessor. Only that can "automatically extract the type".

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename C, typename T>
using Func = const T& (C::*)(void) const;

template<typename PMem, PMem f> class X;

template <typename C, typename T, Func<C, T> F>
class X<Func<C, T>, F> {};

#define MAKE_X(...) X<decltype(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__>

struct Y { const int &getInt() const; };


int main() {
    MAKE_X(&Y::getInt) x;
    return 0;
}
```

The key part is `MAKE_X`. It will emit the same tokens you gave it, both as the argument to `decltype` and unchanged. This is a hack to extract the type of the expression automatically.

Needless to say, it's no where near as good as a proper `auto` parameter.

Comment: Thank you! It surprises me that there is no "hacky" way like defining a function template `template <typename C, typename T> constexpr C helper((C::*)(const T&))` and then extracting the return type via `std::result_of`. But I have no idea if it is possible to specify the function-parameter of `helper` as a compile time constant and hoping that this helps evaluating the return type.

Comment: @M.Winter - You could write it like that. But you'll still end up needing decltype to turn the function call expression into a type. It will likely  lead you to using a macro any way in order to make it less verbose.